# modify text properties in read-only buffer

Tags: text-properties, read-only-mode

I am annotating parts of text in an emacs buffer using text properties.  The code I am using looks something like this:

```
(set-text-properties beg end nil)  ; clear properties
(add-face-text-property beg end city-name-face)
(put-text-property beg end 'field "city-name")
```

where `beg` and `end` are the markers in-between of which the property is set, and `city-name-face` is defined elsewhere in code.

Everything works fine, except when I occasionally press a wrong key and modify the text in the file.  However, I want the text (as sequence of characters) to be immutable and modify only its properties.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use `read-only-mode`. However, that prevents you from setting properties. Fortunately, this can be fixed by using something like `(let ((buffer-read-only nil)) YOUR-CODE-GOES-HERE)`.

Comment: @Lindydancer: Please consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `read-only-mode`, this prevents you from editing the buffer.

However, that prevents you from setting properties. Fortunately, this can be fixed by using something like:

```
 (let ((buffer-read-only nil))
     YOUR-CODE-GOES-HERE).
```